# bash command to select installation option #2 in the script shown

Tags: bash, automation, scripting

I am attempting to create a **script that can install (automate) veracrypt on a CentOS7 system**.

The downloaded veracrypt file comes as a .bz2 file (veracrypt-1.23-setup.tar.bz2). After unzipping the bzip file`bzip2 -dk veracrypt-1.23-setup.tar.bz2`, I then unzip the resulting .tar file `tar -xf /home/$USER/veracrypt-1.23-setup.tar`. At this point I can (if I) manually call the veracrypt script `./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64` from the bash terminal I am presented the following veracrypt installer prompt.

[image]

The veracrypt installer prompt is looking for the user to press either number 1 or 2 on the keyboard and then Enter (which I manually typed into the prompt window shown below for visualization purposes), before pressing enter again to proceed to the license agreement.
[image]

**I am looking for a bash command that will simply choose (or type) number 2 and then input on my behalf so that I don't need to interact with the prompt at all.**

I have tried the following commands in my script to no avail:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cp ./veracrypt-1.23-setup.tar.bz2 /home/$USER
    cd /home/$USER
    bzip2 -dk veracrypt-1.23-setup.tar.bz2
    tar -xf /home/$USER/veracrypt-1.23-setup.tar
    echo -n '2' | ./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64
```

And

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cp ./veracrypt-1.23-setup.tar.bz2 /home/$USER
    cd /home/$USER
    bzip2 -dk veracrypt-1.23-setup.tar.bz2
    tar -xf /home/$USER/veracrypt-1.23-setup.tar
    ./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64 2
```

If I can find the command to pass the input into the script I'm pretty sure I can alter that command to proceed through the rest of the license agreement.

Thanks in advance for the supprot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *Here Document*, see [man bash](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) under the **Here Documents** section. This will allow you to redirect input to the veracrypt installer as if it was coming from `stdin`. You can add to your script:

```
./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64 << EOF
2
EOF
```

And that should take care of you. Let me know if you have any problems or further questions. (you can change the heredoc sigil from `EOF` to anything you like as long as it is consistent) Additionally do not indent the heredoc without seeing the man page for use of the hyphen (though I wouln't recommend doing so as you must use the `tab` character as `spaces` won't do.

Another option is just to pipe `2` to the installer, e.g.

```
echo "2" | ./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64
```

(don't include `-n`)

Both accomplish the same thing. The key is `2` must be available to the installer on `stdin`, not as an argument.

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance and your reply to my post. However I should have mentioned more techniques that I tried in my original post. The two methods you listed above are among some additional things I attempted before posting my question. The two methods do not work but these and other nearly identical solutions are provided throughout the net. For instance I also tried cat "vc_answers.txt." | ./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64 (with the .txt files with per line values listed there).

Comment: When the last line of my script is replaced by your solution the installer is opened like normal; as if I typed the command directly into the terminal. Sorry I can't include the screenshots but this I can confirm that what happens. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It's solvable, but `veracrypt` may be doing something strange. I'll go see if I can find a copy to download and try. Also, try `./veracrypt --help` and see if there is an `--auto-agree-with-license` option, etc..

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try the ./veracrypt --help. Also I will try to find a .readme file that can explain how veracrypt handles stdin. Highly appreaciated.

Comment: The commad - ./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64 --help - yields the following. I think I'll make some progress.

Comment: 1) Getting help or info about ./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64 :
  ./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64 --help   Print this message
  ./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64 --info   Print embedded info : title, default target directory, embedded script ...
  ./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64 --lsm    Print embedded lsm entry (or no LSM)
  ./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64 --list   Print the list of files in the archive
  ./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64 --check  Checks integrity of the archive

Comment: Also, note you can look at the first 530 lines of `veracrypt-1.24-Update4-setup-gui-x64`, it is simply a shell script with a binary blob at the end. I'm looking through it now. Just do `head -n 530 veracrypt-1.24-Update4-setup-gui-x64 > vcinstall.sh` (and you can test without the binary -- may have to adjust the CRC, etc..)

Comment: Running the script with the --help option (./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64 --help) has given me some helpful options; namely ./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64 --target /path/to/directory. The command/option allows the compressed file to be extracted to the /tmp directory. This is what option #2 essentially does in the Veracrypt installer. This has truly helped me. I cant say thank you enough. I love you sooo much right now. You have truly helped me.

Comment: Here is the problem. Beginning line 398 `cp "$0" "$SCRIPT_COPY"` through `exec "$SCRIPT_COPY" --phase2 -- $initargs`. What is happening is the `veracrypt` installer creates a temporary directory, creates a copy of the install script and then replaces the current process with a new one executing the copy of the install script. The effect of this copy/execute is it means the `stdin` from the original is no longer tied to the script that actually runs the install. I'm not going to say this can't be done, but you have to find a way to provide input to the copy of the installer on it's `stdin`.

Comment: Testing an implementation of the automated bash scripts now in a vm. I'll let you know just shortly what occurs. I appreciate you soooo much. Thank you.